# Traveling through Colombo on separate tickets: is my transit visa enough?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, sri-lanka, connecting-flights, yemeni-citizens

I am a Yemeni citizen traveling from Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia to Salalah, Oman as follow :

- From Kuala Lumpur to Colombo on Airasia arriving at 21:55 23/08/2017
- Departing From Colombo to Salalah at 05:00 24/08/2017

I will layover in Colombo for around 7 hours; I have applied and got 2 days transit visa for Sri Lanka.

The email I got from them says :

> This ETA allows ONLY you to transiting through Sri Lanka and you will
>   not be permitted to enter Sri Lanka. Please produce your passport together with return air ticket and proof of sufficient funds to the Immigration officer at the port of entry to Sri Lanka.

I think I will need to go through Immigration to collect the baggage, then go to departures and recheck the baggage and through immigration again. Is that right?

Will my transit visa work or I need to apply for tourist visa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have traveled and I had to show the officer in Colombo a return flight ticket and hotel booking then he let me in to Colombo with the 2 days visa.